# .emacs setq sets a wrong path for a variable

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows

I put the following in my .emacs file to make sure that the "run-python" variable maps to the right path:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\python.exe")
```

When I restart emacs and do M-x run-python; it I get the following error:

```
apply: Searching for program: no such file or directory, c\:/Users/xxxx/python.exe
```

I don't understand why emacs puts "c:/" instead of "c:\" and I assume that is why it cannot find the python's interpreter's path. Am I missing something?

UPDATE: The following works:
C-u M-x run-python RET "python" -i

Make sure you don't put 'python'; and actually use quotation marks like ".

Comment: I suspect this is [Emacs bug #20744](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20744 "python.el tries to undo shell quoting with split-string-and-unquote")

Comment: @npostavs: Looks like it. Please post that as an answer.

Comment: @R  Is your Emacs native w32, or cygwin (post output of `M-x emacs-version`)? Are you using some kind of `bash`-like shell instead of the default cmd.exe (post output of `M-: (w32-shell-name)`)?

Comment: 1st one: GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2015-04-11 on LEG570; 2nd one: "bash"

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not the reason. (And Emacs apparently did not put `c:/`.)

And the problem is not the use of `setq` instead of Customize (though the latter is generally advisable). If you are using the vanilla library `python.el` then you'll see this in the file header:

```
;; Running IPython on Windows needs more tweaking.  The way you should
;; set `python-shell-interpreter' and `python-shell-interpreter-args'
;; is as follows (of course you need to modify the paths according to
;; your system):

;; (setq python-shell-interpreter "C:\\Python27\\python.exe"
;;       python-shell-interpreter-args
;;       "-i C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\ipython-script.py")
```

The error message you see says **`c\:`**.  It does not say `c:\` (and it does not say, as you suggested, `c:/`.

Are you sure that you have `c:\` and not **`c\:`** in your init file? The colon (:) needs to come before the backslash (`\`) or the slash (`/`).

---

Update: It looks like the comment from @npostavs points to the problem: it's a bug in the `python.el` code.  My "answer" speaks to the reason you gave and the reason that @choroba gave - neither is the cause of your problem.

And I guessed that either you mistyped `c\:` or the error message mistakenly really wrote that (instead of `c:\`).

Comment: I'm running elpy. I'm copying the .emacs and error message from *Messages* buffer below:

Comment: (setq python-shell-interpreter "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\python")

Comment: apply: Searching for program: no such file or directory, c\:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda2/python.exe

Comment: I tried the extended setq you mentioned above, still the same error.

Comment: See @npostavs's comment. That is the likely answer: this is a bug. My point in citing that file commentary text was to show that the answer from @choroba is incorrect about not using `setq`. The library itself says you can use `setq`.